# How to add buttons along side a grid in TKinter

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

I am creating a grid for a game in TKinter and I want to have buttons below or along side the grid of blue tiles. I have already tried this:

```
from tkinter import *

class BattleScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid()

        for row in range(20):
           for col in range(20):
                butt1 = Button(self, bg='blue', width=1)
                butt1.grid(row=row, column=col)

        #self.but_frame = Frame(self)
        #self.but_frame.pack(fill=X)
        button1 = Button(self, text='Quit', width=6, command=lambda root=root:root.destroy())
        button1.grid(row=21)


root = Tk()
sheet = BattleScreen(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When this runs, it creates the button below the blue tiles, but since it is all on the same grid and the button is wider, it messes up everything above the button.

The two lines of code you see commented out were my attempts at creating another frame separate from the grid frame to put the buttons on, but I guess you can't do that. Am I wrong?

How can I get buttons below or alongside the blue tiles in the grid without messing up the alignment of the blue tiles?

Comment: Is it battleships by any chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`columnspan` option](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method) to make the button cell span multiple columns:

```
button1.grid(row=20, columnspan=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me, the easiest thing to do is use two frames - one for the grid of buttons, and one for the other buttons. You can then pack these side-by-side to top-to-bottom. Then, use grid for the grid of buttons, and grid or pack for the other buttons.

With this, the grid and the buttons are logically distinct, and you can lay them each out without concern for how they affect the rest of the display. This makes your program *much* easier to maintain and grow over time.

Note that in the following, I removed `self.grid()` from `BattleScreen` -- I think it's bad practice for a frame to place itself in its parent. The parent should control placement.

```
from tkinter import *

class BattleScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        for row in range(20):
           for col in range(20):
                butt1 = Button(self, bg='blue', width=1)
                butt1.grid(row=row, column=col)


class Controls(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.quit = Button(self, text="Quit", width=6, 
                           command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack()

root = Tk()
screen = BattleScreen(root)
controls = Controls(root)
controls.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
screen.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```